# Why does Google Index Http Urls?

Tags: seo, google, https, http, search-results

I have a free SSL certificate (brand new website), redirected all HTTP URLs to HTTPS.
In my sitemap, all URLs are HTTPS. I added my sitemap to the Google search console.
However, when I search my posts in Google, HTTP URLs appear in the results.
Is this a bad situation for Seo?
How can I prevent indexing HTTP URLs? Should I?
I really don't know why do my pages appear as HTTP in the results.

Comment: When you click the HTTP result in Google Search, does it take you to an HTTP page, or is it automatically redirected to the HTTPS version?

Comment: That's an interesting question.   I've seen Google continue to index some HTTP URLs for months after a site switches from HTTP to HTTPS, but I'm surprised that Google might index HTTP URLs for a site that has been HTTPS from the beginning.

Comment: Can you share a link to the site with us?

Comment: "I have a free SSL certificate (brand new website), redirected all HTTP URLs to HTTPS." If it is a brand new website, why do you bother at all to make it reply to HTTP? Make it run only on HTTPS. Browsers now try HTTPS before HTTP anyway.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister yes it automatically redirect to the HTTPs version. I think I understand why. Even if I upload sitemap to search console, Google did not index https versions. Thats why I see http on the results. I dont know why it happened. Now I clicked every https url to index on the search console. I hope it will. Thanks for replies

Comment: Are you doing 301 or 302 redirects?

Comment: "I think I understand why." ... "I dont know why it happened." - You know why, but you don't know why? I can perhaps understand if this was an old website that had previously been HTTP only, but you say this is a "brand new website" and presumably "HTTPS everywhere" from the very beginning? If so then where did Google get the HTTP URLs from? This sounds like there is (or was) a misconfiguration initially? Incidentally, when you see HTTP URLs in the SERPs, what type of search are you performing (standard organic search or a `site:` search)?

Comment: With regards to Google Search Console (GSC), have you added a property for both HTTP _and_ HTTPS? What is the index status / crawl rate for each?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Do you have stats on which browsers use HTTPS for type in traffic?   I would assume that you still need to run HTTP because many browsers will try `http://example.com` when you type `example.com` into your URL bar.

Comment: I don't have statistics, but see recent announcements: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2020/11/17/firefox-83-introduces-https-only-mode/ or https://www.theverge.com/2021/7/14/22577151/google-chrome-https-first-mode-option-lock-icon-experiment   Granted, it may still be an option users have to switch on, but the trend is clearly towards making it the default (I do hope also that company controlled browsers switch it on automatically). Plus some TLDs are in the HSTS preload list anyway now.

Comment: If you are using HSTS preload (like have a `.dev` domain name), then might consider turning off HTTP.   The biggest holdout is opera mini which doesn't support HSTS and has a 1.15% global share of users. https://caniuse.com/?search=hsts   Otherwise HSTS is supported by 98% of users these days.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of any reason besides these. It could also be bug on Google's end.

I'm assuming we've already ruled out automatic redirection per Max's question and your answer.

### Directory & File Permissions are Not Set Properly

If your directory/file permissions are set up incorrectly it is possible that your whole file structure could be indexed. The redirects could be perfectly fine and this could happen if certain files/directories are accessible.

Permissions that would allow this would also present a large security vulnerability. For proof that this can happen please see [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/10363081/migrating-to-https-and-google-not-index-https-links?hl=en&msgid=10378459) Google Support answer.

Do a `site:` search like MrWhite asked - if this is the case, it will be very obvious.

Also as MrWhite asked - make sure you've set up the property in Google Search Console. I recommend using the *Domain Property* option.

---

I use this command **a lot** after freshly installing WordPress on Ubuntu + Nginx/Apache.

```
chown -R www-data: /var/www/html
find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 750 {} \;
find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \;
```

As root of course.

---

### Ensure Canonical URLs are not HTTP

Within Search Console, use the [URL inspection tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en) to check what your User Declared Canonical is. This it will show the status of the page when Google last crawled it.

If you see `http` update your canonical URLs to use
`https`. If there is no User Declared Canonical, it means that you don't have them set - which you should then change, and go back to Search Console and request indexing to your root domain.

Comment: If you run that command be sure to replace info with *your* document root beforehand. Those permissions are specific to _WordPress_.